# MWS remove product from listing

Tags: php, mws

I am having some trouble figuring this out.
In amazon seller central, when you overview a product listing, you have 3 options for its state:

- active
- inactive (closed)
- inactive (out of stock)

I got to the point of getting the product to `inactive (out of stock)` but I can't find anything in the documentation for the other option `inactive (closed)`.

If someone of you is familiar with this I will be grateful if you can point me to the documentation at least. I am writing it with php